# log xml request spring mvc restful

Tags: xml, spring, model-view-controller, rest, request

My requirement is simple. I need to log the incoming xml request.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getAddress")
public String testPrintingRequestBody(@RequestBody  Address address){       
    System.out.println(" print address : "+address) ;
    return "return something";
}
```

Is there any way I can do this. I tried both HandlerInterceptorAdapter and HttpServletRequestWrapper but neither of them helped me.